# YouTube oauth connection

Tags: php, oauth, youtube-api

I try to create a oauth connection to get data from user's channel views. I begin my request like this:

```
public function getAuthorizationUrl()
        {
            // Make redirect
            $this->params = [
                'client_id'    => '###########&',
                'redirect_uri' => '########&',
                'scope'        => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly&',
                'response_type'=> 'code&',
                'access_type'  => 'offline'
            ];
            $redirect_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' . http_build_query($this->params);

            return $redirect_url;
        }
```

But sadly I fail right from the start, because I get this error:

```
Error: invalid_request

Invalid response_type: code&amp;
Request Details
access_type=offline
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly&
response_type=code&
redirect_uri=#####&
client_id=######&
```

Any ideas why I get this error? Any help is welcomed, thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says you have an invalid parameter in there (response type). Have you tried removing those trailing ampersands? http_build_query should take care of that for you

Comment: Thank you very much this was the problem